# String error when saving variables to xml

Tags: xml, string, powershell

i'm trying to save information gathered about the local computer to an XML-file. Everything seems to be running fine, but I get this error about Strings only beeing able to be set as XmlNode properties, but for example:

Any ideas on how to solve it?

```
PS C:\Users\Hkon> $newdrive.name = $_.name
```

results in this error:

```
Cannot set "name" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.
At line:1 char:11
+ $newdrive. <<<< name = $_.name
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Here is my code:

```
$template = "<computer version='1.0'>
    <hardware>
        <serialnr>$serialnr</serialnr>
        <systeminfo>
            <name></name>
            <domain></domain>
            <manufacturer></manufacturer>
            <model></model>
            <bitversion></bitversion>
        </systeminfo>
        <usb>
            <model></model>
        </usb>
        <drive>
            <name></name>
            <volumename></volumename>
            <size></size>
            <freespace></freespace>
        </drive>
        <memory>
            <positioninrow></positioninrow>
            <capacity></capacity>
            <datawidth></datawidth>
            <devicelocator></devicelocator>
        </memory>
        <gpu>
            <name>$gpu</name>
            <status>$status</status>
        </gpu>
        <cpu>
            <name></name>
            <manufacturer></manufacturer>
            <id></id>
            <numberofcores></numberofcores>
            <addresswidth></addresswidth>
        </cpu>
    </hardware>
    <software>
        <printer>
            <id></id>
            <drivername></drivername>
            <portname></portname>
        </printer>
        <allusers>
            <user>
                <name></name>
            </user>
        </allusers>
        <osinfo>
            <caption></caption>
            <serialnr></serialnr>
            <bitversion></bitversion>
            <installdate>$NormalDateTime</installdate>
            <manufacturer></manufacturer>
        </osinfo>
    </software>
</computer>"

$template | out-File C:\Scripts\XML\info.xml
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load("C:\Scripts\XML\info.xml")

#Drive, hardware
$newdrive = (@($xml.computer.hardware.drive)[0])

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk |
ForEach-Object {
    $newdrive = $newdrive.clone()
    $newdrive.name = $_.name
    $newdrive.volumename = $_.volumename
    $newdrive.size = $_.size
    $newdrive.freespace = $_.freespace.toString()
    $xml.computer.hardware.AppendChild($newdrive) > $null
}
$xml.computer.hardware.drive | where-object {$_.name -eq ""} | foreach-object {$xml.computer.hardware.RemoveChild($_)}
$xml.computer.hardware.drive.Count
```

Comment: If you do $_.Name | Get-Member, what is it's type?

Comment: I guess that you are probably right. Might potentially be String[] or some other collection as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested this code ( excluding last 2 lines ) and I have to cast

```
$_volumename, $_.size, and $_.frespace
```

as `[string]`

but all my volumes got a name (`a: c: d: e: f: g: and so on... )`

Can be that some unmounted volume is present in system are you testing?

Try to cast also

```
$newdrive.name = [string]$_.name
```

Here the result after executions of your code adding cast:

[image: Powershell Console]

Where `gwmi` return no value I had error without the cast to `[string]`